# Toast Message doesn't overlay on floating window

Tags: android, android-windowmanager, android-toast

I've created a floating window added by WindowManager with type: TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT.

The context as variable named "mContext" in my custom floating view is referred to getApplicationContext() and I use it to make a toast:

```
Toast.makeText(mContext, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

However the toast message is overlaid by my full-screen floating window; it should overlay on my floating window instead. How can I do it?